# Проблема при генерации PDF файла из изображения SVG с помощью PHP

Tags: svg, php, fpdf, pdf

Делаю [конструктор визиток](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/index2.html), при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить визитку" на сервере сохраняется векторное изображение [image.svg](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/image.svg). Но при нажатии на кнопку "Генерировать PDF" возникает ошибка **FPDF error: Unsupported image type: svg**. Класс FPDF для PHP не поддерживает генерацию PDF из изображений SVG.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, класс или модуль для PHP, который поддерживает генерацию PDF файла из SVG изображения?

Comment: Я так понял, что класс TCPDF мне подойдет для этой задачи, уже даже скачал его, а вот документацию пока не нашел..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи подойдет [класс TCPDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/), также скачать можно [тут](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/), а документация есть на официальном сайте  http://www.tcpdf.org/